# Snapshot bitmap testing with jest?

Tags: jestjs

Jest works great for testing component snapshots.

Is there a way to also use Jest snapshot concept to test JavaScript canvas rendering code by having it compare actual and expected bitmaps?

Answer (score 0):

The regular method works:

```
  expect(bitmap).toMatchSnapshot()
```

The image will be serialized to a JSON string in the snapshot file:

```
 // Jest Snapshot v1, ...
 exports[`renders ok`] = `
 ImageData {
   "data": Uint8ClampedArray [
     0,
     255,
     16,
     255,
     ...
```

However the file is rather big, and you can't easily get a visual diff of expected vs. actual.